# XML signature verification library in C?

Tags: c, xml, verification, xmlsec, xml-signature

Are there any available libraries in C language to verify XML signatures?  I could only find one library for C++ from http://santuario.apache.org/cindex.html .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one: [XML Security Library (xmlsec)](http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/) is a C library based on LibXML2

Answer (score 0):

Besides the Apache XML Security suite, and XMLSec, you might check Microsoft's DCOM-based [XML Signature implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757845(VS.85).aspx). For the Win7 web services stack, there is certainly also an XML Signature implementation but it seems not to be publicly exposed in the API.

Christian

Answer (score -1):

System.Security.Cryptography.Xml

SignedXml sx = new SignedXml((XmlElement)responseDocument.GetElementsByTagName("tns:CreateCertificateResponse")[0]);
        XmlNodeList nodeList = responseDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
        foreach (XmlElement element in nodeList)
        {
          // Load the signature node.
          sx.LoadXml(element);
         sx.CheckSignature(bankSigningCertificate, true);
        }

This is how you can verify signature in c#. Use this library "System.Security.Cryptography.Xml"

For c go through following link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx